# Веб-приложение не реагирует на fetch()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, fetch

Пишу скрипты в Google App Scripts. Решил сделать автоматизацию, чтобы после завершения работы первого скрипта, начинал работу второй в другой таблице и т.д. Погуглив, решил что реализация через веб-приложение самое логичное решение. Развертывание через веб приложение есть, при ручном заходе на ссылку скрипт выполняется. В первом скрипте прописал строку

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://ссылка/exec');
```

При запуске скрипта ошибок никаких не появляется, но веб приложение никак не реагирует.

В чем может быть проблема? Или подскажите более простые способы автоматизации